# Subgroups of given index of a finitely generated group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finitely-generated

Let $G$ a finitely generated group. Prove that for a given natural $n$, there exists finitely many subgroups of index $n$ in $G$.

> I tried to keep on this approach :
> [Finitely generated group has only finitely many subgroups of given index](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494402/finitely-generated-group-has-only-finitely-many-subgroups-of-given-index)

Here is my effort to edit or complete the above idea:

My main emphesize is on this theorem:

> If $H$ is a subgroup of finite index $n$ in a group $G$, Then there
> exists homomorphism $\phi:G\rightarrow S_n$ such that
> $Ker(\phi)=Core(H)=\displaystyle\bigcap_{x\in G}{xHx^{-1}}$.

As $G=\langle \{g_1,\cdots,g_m\}\rangle $, it's sufficient to find $\phi$'s effect over $g_i$s in order to determine whole $\phi$.
Now $\phi(g_i)$ has $n!$ states to be chosen. Therefore, number of whole $\phi$s can be defined, are less than $(n!)^m$.

But if we suppose number of such $H$s is infinite, we must have this fact that infinite number of $Core(H)$s are equal.

Also if the left cosets of $H$ are $H,a_1H,\cdots,a_nH$, we can show $Core(H)=\displaystyle\bigcap_{i=1}^{n}{a_iHa^{-1}_i}$

Any idea is welcome for the rest. Thank You

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you dwell so much with the core of $\;H\;$ ...Isn't it enough to notice that each subgroup of index $\;n\;$ in the group determines a homomorphism to $\;S_n\;$ and the number of these homom's is finite as each of them is completely and uniquely determined by its action of the finite number of generators of $\;G\;$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio That sounds like it just proves finitely many possible homomorphisms for a given subgroup (of given index), not finitely many subgroups (of given index).  Is there a simple reason why distinct subgroups can't induce the same homomorphism?  That seems to be what fardad is trying to figure out.

Comment: I see your (and perhaps also the OP's) point, @zibadawatimmy...Thanks.

Comment: The reason that distinct subgroups give distinct homomorphisms is that the subgroup $H$ is the stabilizer of the point $1$ in the image of the homomorphism to $S_n$ defined by $H$. So distinct subgroups have images with distinct stabilizers of $1$, so the homomorphisms cannot be equal.

Comment: thank you guys, i've never heard stabilizer before

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3538459/10513) question.

Comment: This question (which was posted in 2013) had been closed as a duplicate of a question posted in 2020, so I voted to reopen it.

Comment: @DerekHolt Can you kindly explain what you mean by "$H$ is the stabiliser of the point $1$"?

Comment: @user371231 The action of $G$ defined by the homomorphism $\phi:G \to S_n$ is the action by multiplication on the $n$ left (or right if you prefer right actions) cosets of $H$ in $G$. So it would be more accurate to say that $H$ is the stabilizer of the coset $H$ in this action. But, we can number the cosets $g_1H,g_2H, \ldots, g_nH$ from $1$ to $n$, and it is standard practice to take $g_1 = 1_G$, so the coset $H$ is numbered $1$. That is why I referred to the stabilizer of point $1$.